# Mongoose find on custom _id not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For whatever reason, mongoose seems to be unable to actually locate my document after a `find` call because of a custom ID.

The source of the problem:

```
// ...
models.Item.findOne().where({ _id: item.id }).exec((i) => {
  console.log(item.id, i);
  if (!i) i = new models.Item({ _id: item.id, href: item.href, name: item.name });
  // ...
```

The console just logs the following:

```
> 0 null
> MongoError: E110000 duplicate key error index: items.$_id_  dup key: { : 0 }
```

Indicating it seems to be unable to locate the document with the ID zero, but immediately follows up by complaining the key already exists with a value of 0 when I try to create a new one.

Upon looking at the database, I can clearly see my document with an `_id` of 0.

```
{
  "id": 0,
  // ...
}
```

And this is the schema I'm using:

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 400000, unique: true, required: true },
  // ...
}
```

I've tried `find` and `findOne` in the chained and un-chained versions and `findById`. None of them are yeilding the existing document. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the error parameter in your `exec` callback. It should be:

```
models.Item.findOne().where({ _id: item.id }).exec((err, i) => {...
```

The *second* parameter is the document result.

Comment: I cannot believed I missed that. Thanks.